# Image Compression Power point Presentation 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

I am trying to make a presentation, and am facing a problem.  I am facing picture compression issues . In addition to this saving problem, that pictures become worse quality every time I save the file, I am experiencing problems while trying to insert files. All pictures are inserted blurry. This applies for emf, png and, pdf.

I cannot find these advanced settings from Powerpoint for Mac 2011. How can I import/insert pictures to Powerpoint in their original quality? How can I control the picture compression?

I am using a Yosemite 10.10.2 version. Please help..!

Answer (score 1):

Insert the image> Highlight it> Format picture tab> Compress> Picture quality> Select the desired option.
You'll likely want to choose Picture Quality: "Keep current resolution" 
and Apply to:  "All pictures in this file"
You'll need to do this once for each new file you create, since it's a per-file setting, not a PowerPoint-wide setting.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macpowerpoint/disable-automatic-compression-of-graphics-in/fb140c24-bfb3-49d2-beb8-92ebad3e0de6)